# About throwing my on exception (class instance)

Tags: c++, exception

having searched this site (and some others) and found no answer, I'm at a loss. The problem is fairly simple: I'm writing a class derived from std::exception, and I'm trying to throw an instance of this class. But the compiler won't let me.

For the header I borrowed some lines from runtime_error:

```
class StdException : public std::exception
{
public:
    StdException () {}
    explicit StdException (const StdException&);
    explicit StdException (const std::string&);
    explicit StdException (const char*);
    ~StdException() override { if(what_ptr) delete[] what_ptr; }
    const char* what() const noexcept override;

    StdException& operator= (const StdException&);

private:
    char* what_ptr;
};
```

The code in the .cpp file isn't much either:

```
[snip]
StdException::StdException (const std::string& what_arg)
{
    size_t l = what_arg.size();
    what_ptr = new char[l+1];
    memset(what_ptr, '\0', l+1);
    strcpy(what_ptr, what_arg.c_str());
}
StdException::StdException (const char* what_arg)
{
    [the same in green]
}
[...]
```

The funny part starts when I'm trying to throw such a thing:

```
[[noreturn]] void throw_something () {
    throw new StdException{"Foobar"};
}
```

Only with this heap allocation the compiler will let it through. But that, so I've read several times and understood, is a bad idea. Without, just

```
    throw StdException{"Foobar"};
```

or

```
    StdException e{"Foobar"};
    throw e;
```

I get a *no matching constructor...* complaint from the compiler.

As I said, I'm new to C++. My excuses if this is all to banal.

---

Here's the complete code:

"include/execption.h":

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION_H
#define EXCEPTION_H

#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class StdException : public std::exception
{
public:
    StdException () {}
    explicit StdException (const StdException&);
    explicit StdException (const std::string&);
    explicit StdException (const char*);
    ~StdException() override { if(what_ptr) delete[] what_ptr; }
    const char* what() const noexcept override;

    StdException& operator= (const StdException&);

private:
    char* what_ptr;
};
```

exception.cpp:

```
#include "include/exception.h"

StdException::StdException (const StdException& e)
{
    size_t l = strlen(e.what_ptr);
    what_ptr = new char[l+1];
    memset(what_ptr, '\0', l+1);
    strcpy(what_ptr, e.what_ptr);
}

StdException::StdException (const std::string& what_arg)
{
    size_t l = what_arg.size();
    what_ptr = new char[l+1];
    memset(what_ptr, '\0', l+1);
    strcpy(what_ptr, what_arg.c_str());
}

StdException::StdException (const char* what_arg)
{
    size_t l = strlen(what_arg);
    what_ptr = new char[l+1];
    memset(what_ptr, '\0', l+1);
    strcpy(what_ptr, what_arg);
}

StdException& StdException::operator= (const StdException& e)
{
    size_t l = strlen(e.what_ptr);
    what_ptr = new char[l+1];
    memset(what_ptr, '\0', l+1);
    strcpy(what_ptr, e.what_ptr);
    return *this;
}

const char* StdException::what() const noexcept
{
    return what_ptr;
}
```

And the error is:

*no matching constructor for the initialization of 'StdException'*
*exception.h:11:5 note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided.*

Removing the "empty" constructor didn't help.

Comment: "But the compiler won't let me." what does that mean? Please include the full error message in the quesiton

Comment: Scroll to the bottom: I get a no matching constructor... complaint from the compiler.

Comment: But what is the FULL error message?  That should include details on the constructor it isn't finding.

Comment: Why is your copy-constructor marked `explicit`? Why are you not providing a move constructor/assignment operator?

Comment: `throw new StdException{"Foobar"}` and `throw StdException{"Foobar"}` invoke the exact same constructor of `StdException`. The difference is likely in code you *didn't* include here. Post a proper [mre] please.

Comment: I saw that but as I cannot reproduce the error with the code you posted (https://wandbox.org/permlink/t4Da91Gdn6PlBSp0) i dont know what is the full error message. Please include a [mcve] and the error message verbatim

Comment: You've forgotten to call base class constructor. i.e. `StdException::StdException(const std::string& what_arg) : std::exception(what_arg) { ... } `

Comment: @VictorGubin - that is invoked automatically by the compiler, and is not the problem. If you have an answer, please post it in the actual answer section where it may be properly voted upon.

Comment: As I said, I borrowed some lines from gcc's runtime_error, and there the constructors are explicit. And if I understand the Stroustrup bible correctly, it's ok to do so. Besides, the problem didn't go away when I removed the attribute.

Comment: `what_ptr` is not initialized in default constructor.

Comment: It works for me if I remove `explicit` from the copy constructor.